# how to keep track of image added in asset library through iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app first time I want to retrieve all the images from ALAssetLibrary.The thing is for the next time when the app launches I only want to load if there any image added after the first launcinhg means I want to keep track of all those images which have been added after the last launch time of the app to avoid load whole images asset every time .

Please help me to get out of this situation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadAlbum) name:ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification object:nil];
```

In reloadAlbum load your album groups from assets library to get updated objects.

Apple Documentation:

ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification

> Sent when the contents of the assets library have changed from under
>   the app that is using the data. When you receive this notification,
>   you should discard any cached information and query the assets library
>   again. You should consider invalid any ALAsset, ALAssetsGroup, or
>   ALAssetRepresentation objects you are referencing after finishing
>   processing the notification.
>
> In iOS v4.0, the notification’s object is nil. In iOS v4.1 and later,
>   the notification object is the library object that posted the
>   notification.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to manually keep track of the already "processed" images. You can do it on basis of ALAssetPropertyAssetURL. You will still have to enumerate all the ALAssetGroups and ALAssets, but this is by far faster then touching anything connected to the actual image data.